# How to test that something is posted on the wall in Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, testing, cucumber

I use koala to post something on the wall of my users and it works but I have to write cucumber scenarios for that and I don't know how. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE: I tried to see what will return this:

```
   something = @graph.put_wall_post(to_text(message), attachment, username)
   p something
```

and something is nill even though I have post on my wall.

Answer (score 0):

First make a [Test User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) for your application. Then in your test, post the message to the wall and then verify if it has appeared in the user [news feed](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/feed).

Answer (score 0):

If you post something on facebook using api, you always get some response string from server.

Facebook api returns a status update id if the post was successful.

Read [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/)